# Custom caption text

Tags: captions, environments

How do you set the caption name to say foo instead of figure? I have tried using a custom environment but am encountering several issues.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\figurename}{foo}`? But it depends if you're using `babel` or not.

Comment: Have a look at the `caption` package.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "encountering several issues"? What have you exactly tried and what were the problems you had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The renewcommand was what I was looking for as can been seen below.

```
\renewcommand\<name of environment>caption{foo}
```

If by replacing the name of environment the above command does not work, please refer to the environment documentation particularly the command which prints the caption.